# MongoDB - One Collection Using Indexes

Tags: mongodb, collections, indexing

Ok so the more and more I develop in Mongodb i start to wonder about the need for multiple collections vs having one large collection with indexes (since columns and fields can be different for each document unlike tabular data).  If i am trying to develop in the most efficient way possible (meaning less code and reusable code) then can I use one collection for all documents and just index on a field.  By having all documents in one collection with indexes then i can reuse all my form processing code and other code since it will all be inserting into the same collection.

For Example:

Lets say i am developing a contact manager and I have two types of contacts "individuals" and "businesses".  My original thought was to create a collection called individuals and a second collection called businesses.  But that was because im used to developing in sql where yes this would be appropriate since columns would be different for each table.  The more i started to think about the flexibility of document dbs the more I started to think, "do I really need two collections for this?"  If i just add a field to each document called "contact type" and index on that, do i really need two collections?  Since the fields/columns in each document do not have to be the same for all (like in sql) then each document can have their own fields as long as i have a "document type" field and an index on that field.

So then i took that concept and started to think, if i only need one collection for "individuals" and "businesses" then do i even need a separate collection for "Users" or "Contact History" or any other data.  In theory couldn't i build the entire solution in once collection and just have a field in each document that specifield the "type" and  index on it such as "Users", "Individual Contact", "Business Contacts", "Contact History", etc, and if it is a document related to another document i can index on the "parent key/foreign" Id field...

This would allow me to code the front end dynamically since the form processing code would all be the same (inserting into the same collection).  This would save a lot of coding but i want to make sure by using indexes and secondary indexes that the db would still run fast and not cause future problems as the collection grew.  As you can imagine, if everything was in one collection there might be hundreds of thousands even millions of documents in this collection as the user base grows but it would have indexes and secondary indexes to optimize performance.

My question is:  Is this a common method mongodb developers use?  Why or why not? What are the downfalls, if any?  If this is a commonly used method, please also give any positives to using this method.  thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really big point in Mongo and the answer is a little bit more of an art than science. Having one collection full of gigantic documents is definitely an anti-pattern because it works against many of Mongo's features.

For instance, when retrieving documents, you can only retrieve a whole document out of a collection (not entirely true, but mostly). So if you have huge documents, you're retrieving huge documents each time. Also, having huge documents makes sharding less flexible since only the top level documents are indexed (and hence, sharded) in each collection. You can index values deep into a document, but the index value is associated with the top level document.

At the same time, going purely relational is also an anti-pattern because you've lost a lot of the referential integrity by going to Mongo in the first place. Also, all joins are done in application memory, so each one requires a full round-trip (slow).

So the answer is to do something in between. I'm thinking you'll probably want a collection for individuals and a different collection for businesses in this case. I say this because it seem like businesses have enough meta-data associated that it could bulk up a lot. (Also, I individual-business relationship seems like a many-to-many). However, an individual might have a `Name` object (with `first` and `last` properties). That would be a bad idea to make Name into a separate collection.

Some info from 10gen about schema design: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

**EDIT**

Also, Mongo has limited support for transactions - in the form of atomic aggregates. When you insert an object into mongo, the entire object is either inserted or not inserted. So you're application domain requires consistency between certain objects, you probably want to keep them in the same document/collection.

For example, consider an application that requires that a `User` always has a `Name` object (containing `FirstName`, `LastName`, and `MiddleInitial`). If a `User` was somehow inserted with no corresponding `Name`, the data would be considered to be corrupted. In an RDBMS you would wrap a transaction around the operations to insert `User` and `Name`. In Mongo, we  make sure `Name` is in the same document (aggregate) as `User` to achieve the same effect.

Your example is a little less clear, since I don't understand the business cases. One thing that does come to mind is that Mongo has excellent support for inheritance. It might make sense to put all users, individuals, and potentially businesses into the same collection (depending on how the application is modeled). If one individual has many contacts, you probably want individuals to have an array of IDs. If your application requires that you get a quick preview of contacts, you might consider duplicating part of an individual and storing an array of contact objects.

If you're used to RDBMS thinking, you probably think all your data always has to be consistent. The truth is, that's probably not entirely true. This concept of applying atomic aggregates to the domain has been preached heavily by the DDD community recently. When you look at your domain in depth, like your business users do, the consistency boundaries should become distinct.

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB, and NoSQL in general, is about de-normalising data and about reducing joins. It goes against normal SQL thinking.

In your case, I don't see any reason why you would want to have separate collections because it introduces unnecessary complexity and performance overhead. Consider, for example, if you wanted to have a screen that displayed all contacts, in alphabetical order. If you have one single collection for contacts, then its really easy, but if you have two collections it becomes a more complicated proposition.

Where I would have multiple collections is if your application had multiple users storing contacts. I would then have one collection for each user. This makes it so easy to extract out that users contacts.

Comment: yes i would have multiple user but even then do i need more than one collection if i just index on the collection name and the user id and then reduce/filter the results by the user's session id.  Then i am still only using one collection??

Comment: I know cassandra is about denormalizing, but many of the other's really aren't any different (in that respect) than SQL. Document oriented database is really just about a different way to organize your database. Also mongo is very forgiving when it comes to doing relational schemas